# My bash script on linux shows error while I run individual lines It works fine

Tags: bash

When I am running individual lines of the given bash script gives me output as I desired. But when I run it as a whole It shows a syntax error, I am a newcomer to this language please help me to figure out the problem. Thankyou

```
#!/bin/bash
col1=$( ls -l | head | awk '{print $1}')
echo $col1

col2=$(ls -l | head | awk '{print $2}')
echo $col2
paste <(echo "$col1") <(echo "$col2") | column --table --output-separator "|" | cat -s -n
```

[image]

Comment: `sh` is not bash -- it's a separate shell with less syntax available. When you run `sh yourscript`, you disable bash-only syntax -- even on operating systems where sh is a symlink to bash, it runs in compatibility mode with fewer features when started under the `sh` name.

Comment: Use `./yourscript`, not `sh yourscript` _or_ `bash yourscript` -- that way the `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the top is honored to select an interpreter.

Comment: (btw, this is also part of why we encourage people not to use `.sh` extensions on filenames, _especially_ for scripts that aren't written for execution by sh; for a longer discussion of the topic, see [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Great ! Thank you Charles, for exactly pointing out the problem.  It worked